# Excel chart to show multiple dates for each project

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, timeline

here is the scenario:

Row1 in Excel: Project A: Task A Jan-20; Task B Mar-20; Task C Apr-20 ||
Row2 in Excel: Project B: Task A Feb-20; Task B Mar-20; Task C Apr-20 ||
Row3 in Excel: Project C: Task A Feb-20; Task B Apr-20; Task C May-20

- Task A dates keyed in column B; Task B dates keyed in column C; Task C dates keyed in column D

How can I reflect this into chart to generate each project as a series with multiple dates?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this, but with multiple series for each project (i.e. the projects are the series, not the tasks...).

[image]

Have a look at how this guy did it for one project https://www.projectengineer.net/how-to-create-a-gantt-chart-in-excel/ (image source). You might have to consider all the tasks as if one project, but then use color coding to group by project?